# C# ошибка System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. at D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH

Tags: c#, .net

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
at D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(D3DXMATRIX* , Single , Single , Single , Single )
at SlimDX.Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(Single fov, Single aspect, Single znear, Single zfar)
at ‌⁪⁮‏⁯ Ъ‌​‏ Ъ‌‌ Ъ​ ‏⁬⁫⁪ Ъ‍‍⁭Ъ​⁪‏⁭⁫​⁪‌ ⁬Ъ.‌⁭ ⁯‍⁭‍Ъ ⁮⁮‍⁯⁪⁬⁬⁫‏Ъ⁬⁪ ‍​⁫‍⁫⁭​⁫⁪⁯⁬ ⁬ ⁪Ъ(Single , Single , Single , Single )
at ‌⁪⁮‏⁯ Ъ‌​‏ Ъ‌‌ Ъ​ ‏⁬⁫⁪ Ъ‍‍⁭Ъ​⁪‏⁭⁫​⁪‌ ⁬Ъ..ctor()
at ​‍‍Ъ⁪ ⁪ Ъ⁬⁯⁪⁮‏Ъ‍Ъ‌‍‌ ⁫Ъ‏‌⁮ ⁪ ⁫⁮⁮⁫⁫⁬Ъ..ctor()
at ⁯​​ ⁮⁯ ‏Ъ ‌ ⁮​⁫ ‍‍⁯​⁫‌ ⁬ ⁫ ‍ ⁯⁬‏‍⁮Ъ..ctor()
at Dc\]<3ZF=PzU^k\[IT2 i\[k5\*X!..ctor(lRiz 0O@>~9>(V9aeaa2NWZm" )
at lRiz 0O@>~9>(V9aeaa2NWZm".⁪⁮ Ъ ‌‏ ‍⁬ Ъ‏ ‏⁮⁯‌‏ ⁮‍⁯⁬⁮ ‏⁯‏ Ъ⁯⁫ ⁫ЪЪ()
at lRiz 0O@>~9>(V9aeaa2NWZm".⁯ ⁫Ъ⁮⁯​⁮‏​ Ъ⁭⁬⁭ ‏ ‏ Ъ ⁯‏⁪⁮⁭⁯ ‍‌⁯⁬Ъ Ъ(Object , EventArgs )
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
--------------------------------------—
SIE
Assembly Version: 3.7.0.95
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/SIE.exe
--------------------------------------—
System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/..
--------------------------------------—
System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__..
--------------------------------------—
System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4..
--------------------------------------—
WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking
Assembly Version: 2.9.0.0
Win32 Version: 2.9.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DLL
--------------------------------------—
LibSIE
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/LibSIE.DLL
--------------------------------------—
SlimDX
Assembly Version: 4.0.13.43
Win32 Version:
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/SlimDX.DLL
--------------------------------------—
LibSIE.Misc
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/LibSIE.Misc.DLL
--------------------------------------—
LibSIE.Plugin
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/LibSIE.Plugin.DLL
--------------------------------------—
ObjectListView
Assembly Version: 2.8.0.41320
Win32 Version: 2.8.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/ObjectListView.DLL
--------------------------------------—
LibSWBInterop
Assembly Version: 1.0.6184.236
Win32 Version:
CodeBase:
file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/LibSWBInterop.DLL
--------------------------------------—
System.Drawing.Design
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing.Design..
--------------------------------------—
System.Design
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Design/v4.0_4...
--------------------------------------—
xwqClsclNrzAqFfkPAVGPzqzWIQEA
Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/Laptop_downloads/sytners_iff_editor_3_7_0_95_release/SIE.exe
--------------------------------------—
System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/..
--------------------------------------—
System.Core
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0...
--------------------------------------—
System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0..
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае необходимо установить DirectX

Comment: Что? Почему? Может поясните?